# Why the following code is returning vector size to be 10?

Tags: c++, vector, size

**here i have created a vector of size 5 and then inserted 5 values in it 
    but the vector.size() returns 10 and output is  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4. 
    Why is it so ?
    **

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

 int main()

{   vector < int > k(5);
   for (int i =0 ; i< 5; i++ )
     k.push_back(i);   /*adding 5 values to v*/
   cout << k.size() <<endl;  /*returns 10*/
   for (int i = 0; i < k.size() ; i++)
      cout<< k[i] << '\t'; /* code */
 }
```

Comment: `vector<int> k(5)` create a vector of 5 elements. `vector<int> k{5}` would create a vector of 1 element: 5.

Comment: `>>and then inserted 5 values in it` you are not inserting but adding them to the end of your vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
vector < int > k(5);
```

you already reserved 5 elements in that vector.

Calling `push_back()` adds up to these.

Just write

```
vector < int > k;
```

and the code will work as you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Line `vector < int > k(5);` constructs vector with 5 default-constructed elements.

After that you `push_back` 5 elements - adding 5 more elements to vector.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a vector with the constructor setting the size to 5, it already reserves 5 memory addresses for the contents, although they don't contain anything. By definition, `push_back()` increases the size of the vector by one and adds the element at the back, therefore, the first element you add, would be on `k[5]`, not `k[0]`. This can be fixed by declaring the vector as `vector<int> k;` (without the size), or changing this `k.push_back(i);` to this `k[i] = i;`.

Cheers!